# TRegEx, Pattern that excludes words found in the text

Tags: c++builder

Here is a pattern that excludes two words 'PAK' and 'YT if they are in the searched text:

> \b(?!.*\b(?:PAK|YT)\b)(?!\d{6}-\d(?:[0-9]|A-Za-z)?(?:[A-Za-z]{1,2})?\s(?:PAK|YT)\b)\d{6}-\d(?:[0-9]|A-Za-z)?(?:[A-Za-z]{1,2})?\b

and if these words (PAK/YT) are not present, it applies to expressions:

> 111123-1,
> 111123-1X,
> 111123-1XZ,
> 111123-21,
> 111123-21Z,
> 111123-21ZX,

The problem occurs when word 'YT' appears immediately after the searched pattern, then the pattern reads the word and it shouldn't. Here's an example:

> 111123-9YT,
> 111123-19YT

But if there is a space separating the words YT then the pattern works correctly:

> 111123-9 YT,
> 111123-19 YT

The pattern should applies to expressions:

> 111123-1XZ,
> 111123-21ZX,

But pattern should first check whether the last two letters (YT) do not belong to negative words. Can the pattern be modified to take negative words into account?